# SVG logo appears smaller and then grow like a bump

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

I am using a SVG image logo in my site. When the site loads, the image bumps. It appears smaller and then grow to actual size. It happens very fast. Every time i refresh the page or go to a new page, it happens.

```
<h1>
    <a class="logo" href="/" title="Startpage"><img class="svg" src="/resources/layout/logo.svg" alt="logo" /></a>
</h1>
```

The  tag has fixed height and width and the svg inside has also the same height and width set in css. I am using a js code snippet to make the svg work:

```
$('.svg').each(function(){
        var $img        = $(this);
        var imgID       = $img.attr('id');
        var imgClass    = $img.attr('class');
        var imgURL      = $img.attr('src');

        $.get(imgURL, function(data) {
            // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
            var $svg = $(data).find('svg');

            // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
            }
            // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
            if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
            }

            // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
            $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

            // Replace image with new SVG
            $img.replaceWith($svg);

        }, 'xml');
    });
```

For some reason, I cannot post the link to my site. Can anyone help?

Comment: Why are you doing the img->svg replacement?  Is it necessary?  What sizes have you specified for each of the elements?  And what are the width and height in the SVG file?

Comment: I have remove the svg replacement thing and it works now. Not sure how compatible it is for all browsers. I am using png fallback for IE8 though.